# why google appengine service returning 500 internal server error?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

One of my Google AppEngine services (appspot.com) has suddenly started returning `500` status since March 25th.

When I look into logs, I see for every ah/start log:

> uncaught servlet exception: No class def found error at com.google.appengine.api.utils.systemProperty

I have added Google AppEngine sdk *1.9.48* in the pom, but still facing the issue.

In browser, the service returns:

> 500 internal server error. Please try again in 30 seconds.

We are using Bamboo as our deployment agent and when the script runs, it hits following url: https://xyz.appspot.com/api/liquibase/ update
and curl returns `22` instead of `0` with internal server error `500`. Then the deployment fails.
https://xyz.appspot.com is the service returning `500` status.

Comment: Formatting your question could help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Added quote blocks to describe errors and split long paragraph in more readable pararagraphs

Comment: - Can you show us your pom.xml file?
- Latest App Engine SDK is 1.9.63, have you tried with this one?
- Is it working locally?
- Is your app running on GAE Standard or Flexible?